# Constructing Non Abelian Groups of Given order

Tags: abstract-algebra

The motivating factor behind this question is the comments given for this question asked some hours ago [Group of order $105$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6538/group-of-order-105)

So, given a group $G$ of order $n$, what are different methods for  constructing a non abelian group of order $n$? Well, I have seen a method which Herstein uses in his book. He takes a cyclic group of given order and defines an Automorphism on the cyclic group and then places some restrictions.

I would like to know whether there are anymore methods for obtaining a Non Abelian group of a given order.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31553/finite-nonabelian-groups-of-odd-order/31558#31558

Comment: Also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11001/non-abelian-groups-of-prescribed-order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried taking the semi-direct product of two subgroups (one needs to be a normal subgroup).  The order of G is the product of the orders of the subgroups.  One subgroup needs to be normal.  If the other is not, then the semidirect product is usually (if not always) non-abelian

Comment: Well, yes, but to get a non-Abelian semidirect product, you need to know that there is some non-trivial homomorphism from that group into the automorphism group of the normal one, which is the hard part- there's always a homomorphism with kernel the whole group, which leads to the direct product.